# Make a Wordpress dropdown menu visible when using INTERNET EXPLORER 8

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

The objective: to make the drop down menu [here](http://bit.ly/Y8bNKX) be visible & usable on INTERNET EXPLORER 8.

You can see it & click on links,  but is barely visible, works fine on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE 9 & above etc.

Assigning an image background, using opacity techniques for IE, Ordering DIV's with Z-index, so far have not being useful.

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake on your IE Opacity filter value ..

On `.menu-header ul ul a` in your `styles.css` file

You declared it as `filter: alpha(opacity=9.0);` when it should actually be:

`filter: alpha(opacity=90);` The value is out of 100, not 10 .. which would explain the almost transparent menu.

Comment: That was it!, but how come if I keep that mistake at style.css and the actual fix at <!--[if lte IE 8]> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="..whatever.css" /> <![endif]-->  Such fix does nothing?      How can I repay you?    Regards,  Laura.

Comment: I was using lte since the rest of the fixes were working for IE8.  But I completely agree, having it right from the start is always the best solution.   Thank you!